# JQuery :visible selector does not give proper output

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to find the first "visible" `li`, in the code below this would be `li2-2`.

But for some reason `.children('li:visible')` or `.attr()` gives me the first `<li>` from `<ul>`.

How do I fix this?

```js
alert($("#myul").children('li:visible').attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="descendants">body (great-grandparent)
  <div style="width:500px;">div (grandparent)
    <ul id="myul">ul (direct parent)  
      <li style="visibility:hidden;" id="li1-1">li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
      <li style="visibility:visible;" id="li2-2">li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
      <li style="visibility:hidden;" id="li3-3">li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
      <li style="visibility:visible;" id="li4-4">li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As mentioned in [jquery doc](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible.

That cause your code select all `li`s.

You can use `.filter()` to filtering element has `visibility:visible`

```js
var id = $("#myul").children('li').filter(function(){
  return $(this).css("visibility") == "visible"
}).first().attr("id");
console.log(id);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;">div (grandparent)
  <ul id="myul">ul (direct parent)  
    <li style="visibility:hidden;" id="li1-1">li (child)
      <span>span (grandchild)</span>
    </li>
    <li style="visibility:visible;" id="li2-2">li (child)
      <span>span (grandchild)</span>
    </li>
    <li style="visibility:hidden;" id="li3-3">li (child)
      <span>span (grandchild)</span>
    </li>
    <li style="visibility:visible;" id="li4-4">li (child)
      <span>span (grandchild)</span>
    </li>
  </ul>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select the specific child using `nth-child` selector

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert($("#myul li:nth-child(2):visible").attr("id"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;">div (grandparent)
    <ul id="myul">ul (direct parent)  
      <li style="visibility:hidden;" id="li1-1">li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
      <li style="visibility:visible;" id="li2-2">li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
      <li style="visibility:hidden;" id="li3-3">li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
      <li style="visibility:visible;" id="li4-4">li (child)
        <span>span (grandchild)</span>
      </li>
    </ul>   
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use it in following way:

```
alert($("#myul").children('li[style="visibility:visible;"]').attr("id"));
```

Comment: It is simple but `li`s should not have another style poperty

Comment: You can set a property to `li` as data-visible=true and then check `li[data-visible=true]`